# Map tiles for use offline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, leaflet, offline

I am writting web application using only angularjs. I am currently using Leaflet to display a map on a webpage. I am able to display a map succesfully with out any problems, I am also using leaflet.draw to draw a rectangle and to get all 4 coordinates.

Now, what I want to do is to do this same thing but offline. I want to user to be able to use this application without internet conectivity. I want to user to see America and Atlantic Ocean and be able to zoom in several levels. I dont need street view zoom, but something like state view zoom.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MAPID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Where can I get these map tile to download? In other words, is there a way I can just substite "'http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MAPID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'" 
with a path in my local computer.

Comment: Even if this was possible, good luck storing hundreds of terabytes worth of maps files on the user's pc...

Comment: wow, did not really think it would be more than like several gigs. What about only American and the Atlantic Ocean.

Comment: https://openmaptiles.com/ check this one.

Comment: open maptiles were free? Can I use it for commercial projects ?

Comment: Download TileMill and you can make your own tile sets. @Joe is correct, depending on the range and zoom levels you create, the file sizes can get big.